# Web2py : how to Connect an HTML form with Table in web2py

Tags: forms, web2py

I have made a controller displayform in default.py controller.
I have made a table, "SIGNUP" in db.py
when I add {{=form}} in default/displayform.html, the form gets generated and i am able to control the form with db.py.
Now I add  ... in default/displayform.html removing {{=form}}, the form gets generated, but the data is not submitted into the table "SIGNUP".
How can I connect a  html element with a table in web2py?
Please don't reply if you don't know web2py. I already know to make using {{=form}}. please help me with

Comment: I think your question is missing something -- you have not shown the code you have inserted in your view in place of `{{=form}}`. It's hard to say what's going wrong without seeing that.

Comment: @Anthony I have mentioned above, that if you don't know web2py please dont reply

Comment: I can assure you, I [know web2py quite well](http://stackoverflow.com/users/440323/anthony?tab=reputation). We need to see the code you used to replace `{{=form}}` in the view. Is there a reason you don't want to share that?

Comment: Specifically, your question says, "Now I add ... in default/displayform.html." We need to know what the "..." is in displayform.html. I have some ideas about what might be wrong, but can't say for sure without seeing your controller and view code.

Comment: That code doesn't appear to have anything to do with a database table or a form. I suggest you edit your question (don't post code in a comment). Include your db.py model code, your controller code, and your view code. Explain what you are expecting or hoping to see, and what is happening instead. It might help if you spend a little time with the web2py documentation, particularly the [forms chapter](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators).

Comment: In my db.py model I created a table with two fields. Username and password.

Comment: In my controller default.py i created a function login():`def login():
     
     if request.vars.username and request.vars.password: 
                               session.username = request.vars.username
                               redirect(URL('loggedin'))
     return dict()
def loggedin():
     return dict()`

Comment: Now if i use {{=form}} in view, the form is connected with the database. But how can i customize the view of {{=form}}?

Comment: So i created a form with html tags<form> with two inputs username , password and a submit button. But i know this is not being controlled and is not connected with DB. So please help me how to do it.

Comment: i didnt add anything inside <form> tag like class id .... Is that why my controller cannot connect it?

Comment: `{{=form}}` in the view will do nothing if you haven't defined `form` somewhere, which you have not shown in your code. It will certainly not be "connected with the database" unless it is a `SQLFORM`, which you code does not show. I think you will find it difficult to proceed if you don't read the documentation chapter on forms. Also, please update the question rather than putting new details in the comments.

Comment: Note, it is not clear what you want to do. Presumably you don't want the `login` action to insert a record into the database, but rather look up a record. I strongly suggest you use web2py's built-in `Auth` system instead of building everything from scratch. It might be better to get help on the Google Group since it doesn't appear you have a precise enough question at this point for Stack Overflow.